# Local setting for a subproject in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Sbt [best practices](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Best-Practices.html#Local+settings) state that local settings that are not checked into vcs are best put in a separate sbt file.

However, given a main build:

```
// build.sbt
val p1 = project
```

If I try to customize a setting for `p1` in `local.sbt`, the `p1` project cannot be resolved:

```
// local.sbt
someSetting in (p1, test) := Seq()
// leads to -- local.sbt:1: error: not found: value
```

Is there a way to properly refer `p1` then from local? If not, any better way to do this?